# CakePHP Validation Error Message

Tags: cakephp, validation, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to modify the way CakePHP shows the error message. Below is the generic template that it uses to display errors

```
<div class="error-message">Please enter at least 3 characters.</div>
```

I want to style the error like below.

```
<label class="error">Please enter at least 3 characters.</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this did the job. i was missing the text parameter.

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->error('name', null, array('wrap' => 'label', 'class' => 'error')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

echo $this->Form->label("Please enter at least 3 xter",array('class'=>'error');

Comment: that doesnt do the job. i need to have a label wrapper