# Change Color of Validation Error Message - CakePHP

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, colors

Is it possible to change the color of the error message when a validation error occurs?

I would like to set it to red.  I did find a snippet of css code but this ended up making all text in my form red.

```
form{
color: #ff0000;
}
label{
color: #000;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use the `error-message` style.

```
.error-message {
background-color:#a90329;
color:#fff;
}
```

This works because the default error template is as follows:

```
<div class="error-message">message</div>
```

This may also change the styling of other error messages. To change the class assigned to the error message (so you can make it a separate styling), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362875/cakephp-validation-error-message).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about HTML5's browser validation, there's the [`:invalid` pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3ainvalid).